# Animated screen between a navigation of two screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three screens.
FirstScreen, SecondScreen and a GreenScreen,
im using custom navigation in my navigation routes like so (im using named routes),

```
case secondScreenUIRoute:
        return Platform.isIOS
            ? CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SecondScreen())
            : CustomPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SecondScreen());
```

my green screen looks like so

```
class GreenScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GreenScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: CustomColors.greenLight,
    );
  }
}
```

My basic idea was to have this GreenScreen in between FirstScreen and SecondScreen on navigation(from first to second), but as a fade in fade out effect. Plainly I like to give the user an impression like, when going from FirstScreen to SecondScreen, there seems to be a subtle animation where a green screen is faded in and faded out before reaching SecondScreen.

how Can i achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **animations** package:

https://pub.dev/packages/animations#fade-through

This package contains pre-canned animations for commonly-desired effects. The animations can be customized with your content and dropped into your application to delight your users.

this is an example source code of using the package:

https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations/example

if you want to learn from youtube, you can learn here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GMq45zRVLo

I've used this package before, and I recommend this package because it's easy to use and this package was made by the flutter team